# Eigen Matrix vs Numpy Array multiplication performance

Tags: python, c++, numpy, eigen

I read [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366054/c-performance-in-eigen-librar) that `eigen` has very good performance. However, I tried to compare `eigen` `MatrixXi` multiplication speed vs `numpy` `array` multiplication. And `numpy` performs better (~26 seconds vs. ~29). Is there a more efficient way to do this `eigen`?

Here is my code:

Numpy:

```
import numpy as np
import time

n_a_rows = 4000
n_a_cols = 3000
n_b_rows = n_a_cols
n_b_cols = 200

a = np.arange(n_a_rows * n_a_cols).reshape(n_a_rows, n_a_cols)
b = np.arange(n_b_rows * n_b_cols).reshape(n_b_rows, n_b_cols)

start = time.time()
d = np.dot(a, b)
end = time.time()

print "time taken : {}".format(end - start)
```

Result:

```
time taken : 25.9291000366
```

Eigen:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace Eigen;
int main()
{

  int n_a_rows = 4000;
  int n_a_cols = 3000;
  int n_b_rows = n_a_cols;
  int n_b_cols = 200;

  MatrixXi a(n_a_rows, n_a_cols);

  for (int i = 0; i < n_a_rows; ++ i)
      for (int j = 0; j < n_a_cols; ++ j)
        a (i, j) = n_a_cols * i + j;

  MatrixXi b (n_b_rows, n_b_cols);
  for (int i = 0; i < n_b_rows; ++ i)
      for (int j = 0; j < n_b_cols; ++ j)
        b (i, j) = n_b_cols * i + j;

  MatrixXi d (n_a_rows, n_b_cols);

  clock_t begin = clock();

  d = a * b;

  clock_t end = clock();
  double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  std::cout << "Time taken : " << elapsed_secs << std::endl;

}
```

Result:

```
Time taken : 29.05
```

I am using `numpy 1.8.1` and `eigen 3.2.0-4`.

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations turned on? That makes a massive difference. On my laptop Eigen takes 0.6 sec and Python almost 10.

Comment: @JitseNiesen, probably not, how do you compile with optimizations on? I ran this line `g++ -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/eigen3 time_eigen.cpp -o my_exec`

Comment: @ggael, Thanks. When I run: g++ -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/eigen3 time_eigen.cpp -o my_exec -02 -DNDEBUG, I get this error: g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-02’. I tried too figure this out via google, but to know avail. Do you have any suggestiions? Compiling without `-02` does not help the performance.

Comment: @Akavall The -O2 that ggael wrote is "minus uppercase-o two", not a zero.

Comment: @AviGinsburg, Thanks I must be blind. This does speed things up a ton.

Comment: @ggael, just tested on my mac, using extra `-march=native` would bring us more performance, however the `eigen` impl is still slower (now just slightly slower) than `numpy` version, I guess `numpy` makes use of heavily optimized blas packages, so not easy to beat it with the above `eigen` code, right?

Answer (score 7):

My question has been answered by @Jitse Niesen and @ggael in the comments.

I need to add a flag to turn on the optimizations when compiling: `-O2 -DNDEBUG` (O is capital o, not zero).

After including this flag, `eigen` code runs in `0.6` seconds as opposed to `~29` seconds without it.

Comment: but the `eigen` code is still on par with `numpy` version？

Comment: what does the flag -O2 -DNDEBUG do?

Answer (score 6):

Change:

```
a = np.arange(n_a_rows * n_a_cols).reshape(n_a_rows, n_a_cols)
b = np.arange(n_b_rows * n_b_cols).reshape(n_b_rows, n_b_cols)
```

into:

```
a = np.arange(n_a_rows * n_a_cols).reshape(n_a_rows, n_a_cols)*1.0
b = np.arange(n_b_rows * n_b_cols).reshape(n_b_rows, n_b_cols)*1.0
```

This gives factor 100 boost at least at my laptop:

```
time taken : 11.1231250763
```

vs:

```
time taken : 0.124922037125
```

Unless you really want to multiply integers. In Eigen it is also quicker to multiply double precision numbers (amounts to replacing MatrixXi with MatrixXd three times), but there I see just 1.5 factor:  Time taken : 0.555005  vs 0.846788.

Comment: Thank You! Very interesting, do you have any idea why this is?

Comment: One should check carefully, but I guess that if matrices are floating point then multiplication is done by external library. If not, then it is done by multiplication by a simple "three nested for loops" algorithm. One should note that for matrices of that size proper choice of multiplication algorithm matters

This is confirmed by the file: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c  (lines approx 930 till 1030)

Bul all this does not explain factor 100 in execution speed. Libraries matter, but not THAT much...I would expect at most 10.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a more efficient way to do this eigen?

Whenever you have a matrix multiplication where the matrix on the left side of the `=` does not also appear on the right side, you can safely tell the compiler that there is no [aliasing](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicAliasing.html) taking place. This will safe you one unnecessary temporary variable and assignment operation, which for big matrices can make an important difference in performance. This is done with the `.noalias()` function as follows.

```
d.noalias() = a * b;
```

This way `a*b` is directly evaluated and stored in `d`. Otherwise, to avoid aliasing problems, the compiler will first store the product into a temporary variable and then assign the this variable to your target matrix `d`.
So, in your code, the line:

```
d = a * b;
```

is actually compiled as follows:

```
temp = a*b;
d = temp;
```