Why is the computation speed of double in the Eigen library 3 times faster than that of float?
Here is my code. I created a set of matrix and vector multiplications using double type, and another set using float type. Both sets of multiplications are executed 3 million times in a for loop, and the time taken is recorded respectively. I found that the double type is significantly faster than the float type. I tried different compiler optimization options:
1. No optimization.
2. O1.
3. O2.
I found that regardless of the optimization level, the computation speed of double is much higher than that of float, roughly 2 to 3 times faster. I also tested on different types of processors, and the conclusions were almost the same.
    #include <iostream>
    #include <Eigen/Dense>
    #include <chrono>

    Eigen::Matrix3d A1 = Eigen::Matrix3d::Random();
    Eigen::Matrix3d B1 = Eigen::Matrix3d::Random();
    Eigen::Vector3d C1 = Eigen::Vector3d::Random();
    Eigen::Vector3d D1 = Eigen::Vector3d::Random();

    Eigen::Matrix3f A2 = Eigen::Matrix3f::Random();
    Eigen::Matrix3f B2 = Eigen::Matrix3f::Random();
    Eigen::Vector3f C2 = Eigen::Vector3f::Random();
    Eigen::Vector3f D2 = Eigen::Vector3f::Random();

    int num = 3000000;

    int main()
    {
    std::cout << "start1:" << std::endl;
    auto start1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        Eigen::Vector3d E1 = A1 * C1 + B1 * D1;
        double dd = E1[0, 0];//just prevent compiler optimization
    }

    auto end1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();  
    std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> elapsed1 = end1 - start1; 
    std::cout << "Eigen use: " << elapsed1.count() << " ms.\n" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "start2:" << std::endl;
    auto start2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        Eigen::Vector3f E2 = A2 * C2 + B2 * D2;
        float dd = E2[0, 0];//just prevent compiler optimization
    }

    auto end2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> elapsed2 = end2 - start2;
    std::cout << "Eigen use: " << elapsed2.count() << " ms." << std::endl;
    }

The following figure shows the result on i7-13700k, win10 X64 platform,  vs2022 x64 compiler with optimization O2.
This is the result figure
double:
Eigen use: 38.4053 ms.

float:
Eigen use: 92.1853 ms.

Can someone help me understand why? Thank you very much.

The following content is the revised version after compared to Intel compiler.
I am very grateful to pptaszni for the analysis provided. Following his suggestions, I modified the code. I then compiled and ran it using MSVC X64 in VS2022. I also compiled and ran it using Intel's C++ compiler. My calculations mainly target a large number of 3x3 small matrices. I found that in MSVC X64, double is faster than float, but for Intel Compiler the speed are very similar. What I don't understand is why the program compiled by the Intel compiler is so much faster than the one compiled by MSVC. Can anyone explain this?

#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>

Eigen::Matrix3d A1 = Eigen::Matrix3d::Random();
Eigen::Matrix3d B1 = Eigen::Matrix3d::Random();
Eigen::Vector3d C1 = Eigen::Vector3d::Random();
Eigen::Vector3d D1 = Eigen::Vector3d::Random();

Eigen::Matrix3f A2 = Eigen::Matrix3f::Random();
Eigen::Matrix3f B2 = Eigen::Matrix3f::Random();
Eigen::Vector3f C2 = Eigen::Vector3f::Random();
Eigen::Vector3f D2 = Eigen::Vector3f::Random();


    static void Floats(benchmark::State & state)
    {
        for (auto _ : state)
        {
            Eigen::Vector3f E2 = A2 * C2 + B2 * D2;
            float dd = E2(0, 0);
            benchmark::DoNotOptimize(E2);
            benchmark::DoNotOptimize(dd);
        }
    }
    BENCHMARK(Floats)->Iterations(50000000);

    static void Doubles(benchmark::State & state)
    {
        for (auto _ : state)
        {
            Eigen::Vector3d E1 = A1 * C1 + B1 * D1;
            double dd = E1(0, 0);
            benchmark::DoNotOptimize(E1);
            benchmark::DoNotOptimize(dd);
        }
    }
    BENCHMARK(Doubles)->Iterations(50000000);


This is the MSVC X64 result:
Run on (8 X 3418 MHz CPU s)
CPU Caches:
  L1 Data 48 KiB (x8)
  L1 Instruction 32 KiB (x8)
  L2 Unified 2048 KiB (x8)
  L3 Unified 30720 KiB (x1)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                            Time             CPU   Iterations
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Floats/iterations:50000000        51.0 ns         51.2 ns     50000000
Doubles/iterations:50000000       19.2 ns         19.1 ns     50000000


This is the INTEL C++ compiler X64 result:
Run on (8 X 3418 MHz CPU s)
CPU Caches:
  L1 Data 48 KiB (x8)
  L1 Instruction 32 KiB (x8)
  L2 Unified 2048 KiB (x8)
  L3 Unified 30720 KiB (x1)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                            Time             CPU   Iterations
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Floats/iterations:50000000        2.18 ns         2.19 ns     50000000
Doubles/iterations:50000000       2.22 ns         2.19 ns     50000000

Besides this, I've heard that results generated by the Intel compiler are not precise. Can the Intel compiler lead to imprecise calculations? Could someone analyze this?

Are you sure you are measuring correctly? Because clang can optimize the loops away. dd is unused variable, so assignment might not prevent anything very much.

Side note, do NOT use chrono for time measurements and certainly not high_resolution_clock it can map to the non-monotonic system_clock.  nanobench might be interesting for you too. (It is a header file only benchmark tester). In the end you would always need a profiler to check out what the EXACT bottleneck is in your code. A profiler will also show you if code is called at all (and it might help to put bodies of loops in seperate functions for that),

I am pretty sure the measure is correct， because I can close all types of optimization， no matter O1,O1, or without optimization,  double is absolutely faster than float.     chrono is no problem,  because I can increase the number of scale, up to minutes,  I can still obesrved that double is faster than float.   I already give the code,  you can easily verify my conclusion.

I already tested to put the loop inside the function,the result is same

Are you sure that you have allowed the compiler to use SIMD instructions? SSE2, AVX or better AVX2 if your CPU supports it. You have to go to C/C++ Enable Parallel Code Enable Extended Instruction Set and Inline Any. Floats are generally a little bit faster than doubles but there isn't much in it these days so much work has gone into optimising double arithmetic that it is only worth using floats if you have very large volumes of data. SIMD with floats should be about 2x faster than doubles provided that you are not limited by memory bandwidth. Worth trying Intel ICX compiler too (faster).

I do use the SIMD，I aslo tested SSE2,AVX,AVX2,AVX512,  but the conclusion is same.  I post this question because I do really did many kinds of tests, but I cant explain why.  thats why I  post the code,  you can test my code and get the same results

In that case I'd suggest giving it a whirl with the Intel compiler - their VTune tool will be able to show you exactly where the code is spending its time. Code generation is almost always better than MSVC and it installs and runs in the MSVC environment as another optional C/C++ compiler.

I have posted a comparison between Intel and MSVC. Could you please help analyze it? Thank you very much.

https://godbolt.org/z/szvfa6P6h - maybe you can use godbolt to compare the assemblies GCC vs MSVC. However I don't know how to configure MSVC to use Eigen library. On the GCC side you can see that mulss and corresponding mulpd instructions are used.

I have never seen any imprecise results from the Intel compiler. Its cbrt is the most accurate of all major compilers (same with some other functions I use and have tested extensively). MSVC sincos is a crock of the proverbial and its cbrt also sub par. Intel ICX is capable of aggressive loop unrolling and vectorisation with the right options ~10% faster. I think in this instance the Intel compiler may have optimised your code out of existence. It is just too fast to be credible. A side effect like returning a result to (conditionally) print out will help prevent it from doing this.

Without context, benchmarking 3x3*3x1 multiplications is a bit pointless. Where do the inputs come from and what do you do with the results (in your real application)? Do you have multiple independent of these operations, or do they depend on each other? Generally, if your matrix row-number is not a multiple of 4 (for float) or 2 (for double), Eigen will have trouble effectively vectorizing it (and with AVX, there won't be much difference between 4 floats and 4 doubles, assuming all data is in cache).

Not a complete answer, but it might help you to benchmark your code better and avoid potentially wrong results (e.g. due to some lines being optimized-out). Instead of using std::chrono, use a benchmarking library, e.g. the one from google and write a benchmark:
#include <Eigen/Dense>

#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>

Eigen::Matrix3d A1 = Eigen::Matrix3d::Random();
Eigen::Matrix3d B1 = Eigen::Matrix3d::Random();
Eigen::Vector3d C1 = Eigen::Vector3d::Random();
Eigen::Vector3d D1 = Eigen::Vector3d::Random();

Eigen::Matrix3f A2 = Eigen::Matrix3f::Random();
Eigen::Matrix3f B2 = Eigen::Matrix3f::Random();
Eigen::Vector3f C2 = Eigen::Vector3f::Random();
Eigen::Vector3f D2 = Eigen::Vector3f::Random();


static void Floats(benchmark::State &state) {
  for (auto _ : state) {
    Eigen::Vector3f E2 = A2 * C2 + B2 * D2;
    float dd = E2(0, 0);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(E2);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(dd);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(Floats);

static void Doubles(benchmark::State &state) {
  for (auto _ : state) {
    Eigen::Vector3d E1 = A1 * C1 + B1 * D1;
    double dd = E1(0, 0);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(E1);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(dd);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(Doubles);

On my machine the results of both operations are almost the same:
Run on (4 X 2688.01 MHz CPU s)
CPU Caches:
  L1 Data 48 KiB (x2)
  L1 Instruction 32 KiB (x2)
  L2 Unified 1280 KiB (x2)
  L3 Unified 12288 KiB (x1)
Load Average: 0.04, 0.29, 0.16
-----------------------------------------------------
Benchmark           Time             CPU   Iterations
-----------------------------------------------------
Floats           3.41 ns         3.41 ns    208083014
Doubles          3.31 ns         3.31 ns    210535117

with floats indeed being slightly slower (not sure why).
Maybe simple vector multiplication and addition is too fast to observe the difference between float and double, if instead I compare the speed of 100x100 matrix inversion and multiplication:
constexpr int N = 100;
Eigen::MatrixXd bigD = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(N, N);
Eigen::MatrixXf bigF = Eigen::MatrixXf::Random(N, N);

static void FloatsMatrix(benchmark::State &state) {
  for (auto _ : state) {
    Eigen::MatrixXf inv = bigF.inverse();
    Eigen::MatrixXf identity = inv * bigF;
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(identity);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(FloatsMatrix);

static void DoublesMatrix(benchmark::State &state) {
  for (auto _ : state) {
    Eigen::MatrixXd inv = bigD.inverse();
    Eigen::MatrixXd identity = inv * bigD;
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(identity);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(DoublesMatrix);

then on my machine I can see that using double is roughly 2 times slower:
Run on (4 X 2688.01 MHz CPU s)
CPU Caches:
  L1 Data 48 KiB (x2)
  L1 Instruction 32 KiB (x2)
  L2 Unified 1280 KiB (x2)
  L3 Unified 12288 KiB (x1)
Load Average: 0.41, 0.18, 0.12
--------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark              Time             CPU   Iterations
--------------------------------------------------------
FloatsMatrix      280250 ns       274401 ns         2564
DoublesMatrix     507990 ns       507992 ns         1253


Question was: Why is the computation speed of double in the Eigen library faster than that of float?

@Elmir thanks for clarification. To summarize my answer: "it probably isn't".

thanks， I used your code and tested the performance with benchmark.h，  I also downloaded the intel C++ compiler， I found that when I use the MSVC compiler， double is faster than float。  When I use the Intel compiler ， their speed are very close when the Matrix size is smaller( e.g. 3X3 or 4x4), but for large Matrix, float is faster.   Compared to Intel compiler, MSVC is very slow,  both double  and float is 3 times slower than intel compiler, why?

I have posted a comparison between Intel and MSVC. Could you please help analyze it? Thank you very much.@pptaszni

@zymaster hard to tell, you would probably need to compare the generated assemblies, which with Eigen might be a bit time consuming.

My application involves a large number of multiplications between 3x3 matrices and 3x1 vectors, primarily used for coordinate transformations of 3D objects. Potentially, tens of thousands of these multiplications may be executed per millisecond. Is Eigen the best option for this purpose, or are there faster methods available for operations on small 3x3 matrices? Please help me translate this into English. @pptaszni

@zymaster I think we can risk an assumption that Eigen is one of the fastest linear algebra libraries, but like always "it depends". Best would be to write some complex function that is representative for your heavy 3x3 matrix/vectors operations, and then benchmark it. Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366054/how-can-the-c-eigen-library-perform-better-than-specialized-vendor-libraries

@zymaster MSVC is known to generate less efficient codes than other mainstream compilers like Clang and GCC. The Intel compiler (now based on Clang) often generate a better SIMD code than others (especially MSVC which one of the worst for that though MSVC developers progressively improve this the last decade). In other cases, the (new) Intel compiler often perform similarly to Clang. This is why the Intel compiler is very often used in high-performance applications on x86-64 platforms.

@zymaster For 3x3 matrices, you can use templates so for Eigen to generate a specific code for such matrices. This is pretty critical for small matrices since loops are expensive at this scale and optimizing compilers can generate a faster SIMD assembly code (especially with AVX-512 thanks to masking). Generic codes will be always sub-optimal. At this scale, even a function call is pretty expensive (since mainstream x86-64 CPUs can execute 2 SIMD-FMA/cycle, each operating on 8 floats or 4 doubles numbers -- 5 of the 8 float SIMD lane will certainly be unused/wasted with a generic code).

@zymaster Oh and on Intel server CPUs this is even worst since they often have (2x) AVX-512 units. This means SIMD units with 16 floats and 8 double while 3x3 matrices will certainly use only 3 lanes (18-37% of all lanes). The same thing is true on future AMD Zen5 client/server CPUs and some rare Intel ones. In this case, a clever compiler can store the whole 3x3 float matrix in 1 AVX-512 register and perform SIMD shuffles/FMAs.

Your explanation is very detailed. I, a layman, completely understand what is going on. Please put your replies in a separate answer. I think it will help many people. Because many people install and use the compiler by default, without knowing that there is such a big performance gap between the compiler and the CPU instruction set. Thank you again for your reply。@JérômeRichard

@zymaster: also related: Idiomatic way of performance evaluation? re: some benchmarking pitfalls that benchmarking libraries can help avoid, and that you need to worry about even when using them.
